# Lokijs: result.where is not a function

Tags: javascript, lokijs

I am using lokijs to create a database, `db` represents the database of lokijs in the code below:

```
var users;
db.loadDatabase({},function(){
    users=db.getCollection('users');
});
var result=users.find({'city':{'$contains':searCon.username}});
var obj=result.where(function(uu){return uu.username == 'admin123'; });
```

But I get the following error:

> TypeError: result.where is not a function

```
var obj=result.where(function(uu){return uu.username == 'admin123'; });
```

Comment: The reason why 1 rep users are not allowed to embed images is to prevent them from embedding code or error screenshots. So please type  the error as text not an image. I am giving you -1 until then.